# SqlDataReader command timing out on Close/Dispose

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to read from my SQL Server database by using a `SqlDataReader`. I'm not interested in reading what's returned from the reader and just want to see if the initial `command.ExecuteReader()` will time out. Something I noticed with my code is that it actually times out when I try to close the reader.

Is it timing out on close because I haven't finished reading everything from the `SqlDataReader`?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            break; // Don't need to actually read what's in here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
    reader.Close(); // Fails here 
}
```

Also am I misunderstanding something about `SqlDataReader`? Is it wrong to assume that `command.ExecuteReader()` loads all the records first and I can read them? Or is it a constant stream of data that could time out there?

Please note that I DO want my program to timeout, I just don't understand why it's timing out on closing the reader and not on the `command.ExecuteReader`.

Comment: *"Is it wrong to assume that command.ExecuteReader() loads all the records first and I can read them?"* - Yes. Readers read as they go; in this case, it's reading the TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol. Until `reader.Read()` returns `false`, it's still pulling records from the server.

Comment: You will likely need to call .Cancel() on your "command" object, if you're not going to complete the read of all records from the data reader.  Then you should be able to .Close()

Comment: @Craig Yes, if I use `command.Cancel()` it will close fairly quickly. I'm just wondering why it times out to begin with? Is it because I haven't finished reading everything even though I used `break` to get out of the stream and it's trying to finish reading on it's own?

Comment: Side note: A `using {...}` block closes the object for you, no need to call `reader.Close();`

Comment: @m1771vw, it's just the behaviour of the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader (yes, when you haven't "completed" the read of all records).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0  Sometimes, in our lives as programmers, we just have to do the "what" without always understanding the "why" .....

Comment: @LarsTech ty! I thought so too, I had originally added it to make sure I wasn't making things up with `using {...}`